# Alternatives to using Aggregate subquery as parameter for parent query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a very large non-partitioned table that is taking a long time to return results from this query:

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT Listagg(VALUE_STRING, ', ') 
            WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY VALUE_STRING) AS VALUE_STRING 
     FROM   ATTRIBUTE_DATA AD 
     WHERE  AD.id = DT.dataid 
            AND AD.defid = 3070056 
            AND AD.attrid = 4 
            AND vernum = (SELECT Max(vernum) 
                        FROM   ATTRIBUTE_DATA AD
                        WHERE  AD.id = DT.dataid 
                                AND AD.defid = 3070056 
                                AND AD.attrid = 4) 
            AND defvern = (SELECT Max(defvern) 
                        FROM   ATTRIBUTE_DATA AD
                        WHERE  AD.id = DT.dataid 
                                AND AD.defid = 3070056 
                                AND AD.attrid = 4) 
    GROUP  BY AD.id) AS PlantNumbers
FROM WORKTABLE W 
    left outer join CUSTOM_FORMS FORMS 
                ON FORMS.volumeid = w.subwork_subworkid 
                    AND FORMS.versionnum = -1 
                    AND FORMS.rowseqnum = 1 
    left outer join DATATREE DT
                ON DT.name = FORMS.document_number_text_field 
                    AND DT.ownerid = -2000 
                    AND DT.SUBTYPE = 144 
                    AND DT.dataid NOT IN (SELECT dataid 
                                        FROM   dtreeancestors 
                                        WHERE  ancestorid = 3109628)
```

When I take just this subquery alone it takes 12 minutes to run:

```
SELECT Max(vernum) 
FROM   ATTRIBUTE_DATA AD
WHERE  AD.id = DT.dataid 
   AND AD.defid = 3070056 
   AND AD.attrid = 4
```

How can I improve this script.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not even sure what your question really is, but for this query:

```
SELECT Max(vernum) 
FROM   ATTRIBUTE_DATA AD
WHERE  AD.id = DT.dataid 
   AND AD.defid = 3070056 
   AND AD.attrid = 4
```

You want an index on `ATTRIBUTE_DATA(dataid, defid, attrid, vernum)`.

That might speed things up a bit.

Comment: Is there not a more efficient way to accomplish this? The table has 600 million rows so I'm not sure an index alone would be enough, ill try it tomorrow when I get the chance though. if it helps that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Starting at the beginning, how big is WORKTABLE as that seems to be driving the query ? If it is ten million rows, then you'll be doing 10 million aggregations. That's a lot of work and it will be painful.

WORKTABLE joins to CUSTOM_FORMS and then DATATREE. Since you are pulling data via the DATATREE.data_id, you are only interested in WORKTABLE entries that are linked to a DATATREE, so you can go with regular inner joins, not outer joins.

For every DATATREE dataid, you do the aggregate in a scalar subquery. The GROUP BY AD.id is superfluous and a scalar subquery will return an error if the query returns more than one row anyway.

We don't know how many rows in ATTRIBUTE_DATA you'll be aggregating for each WORKTABLE entry. It will have to be less than a few hundred, otherwise you are likely to blow the 4000 character limit for LISTAGG.

Oracle is primarily a relational database. It looks like your application is trying to implement some generic/schemalass model in there where everything can be customized, rather than storing attributes as columns in tables. If you really need to go that route, Oracle/RDBMS is not a good platform to build it on. If it is too late for that, look at partitioning, materialized views and function based indexing and try to layer a relation model on top of the generic one.

Comment: Hey Gary, thanks for the response. I'm not sure function based indexing would work here, i tried it with the MAX function but it wasn't allowed. I think partitioning the larger tables would definitely provide some improvements as well as materialized views on sub-queries like `SELECT MAX FROM...` I'll have to test things out further to see though

Comment: The WORKTABLE has 34k rows, DATATREE  has 19million and FORMS has 1million.